# Unbound Local Error - Python - File I/O - Dictionaries

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I have successfully created 5 different functions. The functions add to a dictionary, find a value and its keys of a dictionary, remove values or keys from a dictionary, saves the dictionary to a file, and lastly, reads the file back to me. Now my goal is to create a main function that allows a user to add, remove, find, or clear the dictionary using these functions i have created until the user decides they want to end the program. All my functions work, but i keep getting the same error for all functionalities of the program. The error is as follows: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'diction' referenced before assignment`. I will paste the code below. Any ideas, advice, or tips?

```
def primary():
    diction = {}
    readit()
    decision = raw_input('Which would you like to choose: add? find? remove? clear? or end?     ')
    if decision == 'add':
        key = raw_input('Which would you like to add?     ')
        value = raw_input('What would you like to link to your new addition?     ')
        addit(diction, key, value)
    elif decision == 'find':
        key = raw_input('What would you like to find?     ')
        findit(diction, key)
    elif decision == 'remove':
        key = raw_input('What would you like to have removed or edited?     ')
        value = raw_input('Which value would you like to remove?     ')
        removeit(diction, key, value)
    elif decision == 'clear':
        diction = []
    elif decision == 'end':
        saveDB()
    if decision == 'add' or 'find' or 'remove' or 'clear':
        primary()
    elif decision == 'end':
        exit
```

Comment: Where is `diction` initialized ? Should you not be doing that first ?

Comment: Note that the second-last if should be `if decision in ('add', 'find', 'remove', 'clear')` - what you have won't do what you think.

Comment: How can i have it repeat until end is chosen without going through primary() each time? because this will set diction = {} each time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, diction is not being defined before the if statements. This means that, while yes, you do define it in one of your elifs, it's not existent in your other ifs.

You need to initialize diction either in your main, so its globally available, or at the top of primary() before your ifs and elifs.

Comment: even if my readit() function returns diction before my primary()?

Comment: @user3014014 readit() isn't being set equal to anything, did you mean to type diction = readit() ?